# How to generate specific JSON from python dict?

Tags: python, json

I want to create json data which exactly looks like this:

```
[
      {
        "mainDetail": {
            "number": "12345",    
            "inStock": 111
        }
      },
      {
        "mainDetail": {
            "number": "54321",
            "inStock": 222
        }
      }
]
```

The data `"number"` and `"instock"` are read from python dict:

```
articleDict = {}
d=[{'number': x, 'inStock': y} for x,y in articleDict.items()]
print json.dumps(d, indent=4)
```

This is what i get so far:

```
[
    {
        "number": "12345",
        "inStock": 111
    },
    {
        "number": "54321",
        "inStock": 222
    }
]
```

I am just missing the `"mainDetail"`, I'm at an impasse with my ideas. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: `d=[{'mainDetail': {'number': x, 'inStock': y}} for x,y in articleDict.items()]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d=[{"mainDetail" : {'number': x, 'inStock': y}} for x,y in articleDict.items()]
```

You need to add this "mainDetail" when creating your list.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the expected result.